# Android Phone Not Detecting MMS Until After Message is Read

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating an Android app in C# using Xamarin and am not understanding why my ContentObserver, `MMSObserver` is not noticing a change when a MMS message is received, but does notice a change after the message is read. Can a ContentObserver notice when a MMS message is received? If so, what should add/change regarding my code?

MMSObserver:

```
public class MMSObserver : ContentObserver
{
    private readonly Android.Net.Uri _uri;
    private static readonly string TAG = "MMS Observer";
    public static readonly string MMS_RECEIVED = "MMSObserver.intent.action.MMS_RECEIVED";

    public MMSObserver (Android.Net.Uri uri): base(null)
    {
        _uri = uri;
    }

    public override void OnChange(bool selfChange)
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, "Observed a change.");
        Task.Run(() => {
            Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(MMS_RECEIVED);
            AndroidApp.Context.SendBroadcast(mmsIntent);
        });
        base.OnChange(selfChange);
    }
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    // Constants for the MMS Observer.
    static readonly Android.Net.Uri MMS_URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://mms");

    // Create the MMS Observer.
    MMSObserver mmsObserver = new MMSObserver(MMS_URI);

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Other code not shown

        // Register the MMS Observer to the content resolver.
        ContentResolver.RegisterContentObserver(MMS_URI, false, mmsObserver);
        ContentResolver.NotifyChange(MMS_URI, mmsObserver);

    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        ContentResolver.UnregisterContentObserver(mmsObserver);
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Snippet of Manifest.xml:

```
application android:label="App.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".MMSReceiver">
        <!-- IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority is equal to 1000 -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ContentObserver` only works with a `ContentProvider` that calls [one of the *NotifyChange()* methods on a *ContentResolver*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) when the contents of the provider change. If the `ContentProvider` does not call `NotifyChange()`, the `ContentObserver` will not be notified about changes.

That means you need to call notify method manually :

```
ContentResolver.NotifyChange(MMS_URI, null);
```

Note : [The second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.contentresolver.notifychange?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) can be `null` .